# IE11 stretches border-image

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a CSS3 image-border to work across modern browsers and I find that IE11 stretches 1px-wide image slices when they should be solid.

Here is my test image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVIZ8.png - note how the centre region (1px wide) is solid white.

My CSS:

```
div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 24px 10px 25px;

    border-image-source: url(...);
    border-image-slice: 11 24 10 25 fill;
    border-image-width: 11px 24px 10px 25px;
    border-image-outset: 0s;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
}
```

The image's regions are (in a 50x50 image):

```
 Top-left:      0, 0 to 25,10 (25x11)
 Top-span:     25, 0 to 25,10 ( 1x11)
 Top-right:    26, 0 to 49,10 (24x11)
 Left-span:     0,11 to 24,39 (25x29)
 Centre:       25,11 to 25,39 ( 1x29)
 Right-span:   26,11 to 49,39 (24x29)
 Bottom-left:   0,40 to 24,49 (25x10)
 Bottom-span:  25,40 to 25,49 ( 1x10)
 Bottom-right: 26,40 to 49,49 (24x10)
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdgbotke/

Rendering comparison:

Chrome 44:

[image]

IE11:

[image: IE11 rendering]

**Update**  I noticed that Edge on Windows 10 renders it identically to Chrome, so I suppose this must be a bug in IE11 then.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a matter of colors or simple graphic that can be drawn from them, the b`ackground`, `background-repeat`, `background-position` and  `background-size` could be an alternative.

```css
div {
  padding:12px 25px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF0000, #FF0000 ) 0 0 no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top , #B335B2, #B335B2) 0 bottom no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, #00FFD8, #00FFD8) 0 0 no-repeat ,
    linear-gradient(to top, #CFBFF3,#CFBFF3) top right no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, #F6D830,#F6D830)  bottom right no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, #5C35B3,#5C35B3)  top right no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top,#0000FF,#0000FF) top no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top,#00FF42,#00FF42) bottom no-repeat;
  background-size:
    24px 11px, 
    24px 11px, 
    24px 100%,
    24px 11px, 
    24px 11px, 
    24px 100%, 
    100% 10px, 
    100% 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>blargh</p>
</div>
```

Box-shadow can help too :

```css
div {
  margin: 20px 24px;
  padding:1px;
  box-shadow:
    0 -11px #0000FF,
    0 11px #00FF42,
    24px 0 #5C35B3,
    -24px 0 #00FFD8,
    -24px -11px #FF0000,
    -24px 11px #B335B2,
    24px 11px #F6D830,
    24px -11px #CFBFF3
}
```

```html
 <div>
  <p>blargh</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but no - the test image I provided is a placeholder for a complicated raster image that cannot be substitute for with CSS gradients.

Comment: @Dai , you would be surprised from what you can draw from gradient or shadows :) among many you could find http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/eywzI,  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/tkzoa , http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yJfjl, and for cheeeeeze http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/thkib ;) . Without seing your image, impossible to tell of course, but did you mind the multiple image (gradients are like image).

Comment: @Dai, beside, when i used too face IE6 bugs(or others few browsers) , i used too walk around to avoid to trigger them as much as possible. I still do nowdays :), it often spares you time to pick up another unbugy  method :)